# Pandas dataframe and assigning values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

There is a behavior of pandas dataframes that I can't explain. I wish somone could walk me through this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 5, 10]]), columns=["Jan", "Fév", "Mar"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[4, 4, 4]]), columns=["Jan", "Fév", "Mar"])

df
    Jan Fév Mar
0   1   5   10

df2
    Jan Fév Mar
0   4   4   4
```

So the booleans df < df2 and df >= df2 are respectively:

```
df < df2
    Jan     Fév     Mar
0   True    False   False

df >= df2
    Jan     Fév     Mar
0   False   True    True
```

However if I do this sequence of code:

```
df3 = df2
df3[df < df2] = 0
df3[df >= df2] = 7
```

I will get as a result:

```
df3
    Jan Fév Mar
0   7   7   7

df2
    Jan Fév Mar
0   7   7   7
```

My question is: Why do my code also modifies the values of df2?

Is it because of the df3 = df2?

Comment: `df`, like other objects in Python, is address based. So `df3=df2` means they share the same data/memory. You need to do `df3=df2.copy()`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `pandas` there is difference between *views* and *copies*, by using `=` you are creating `view`, changes applied to it are also applied to original, as opposed to copy. Consider following simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3]})
df2 = df1
df3 = df1.copy()
df3['x'] = 0
print(df1)
```

output

```
   x
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

then

```
df2['x'] = 0
print(df1)
```

gives output

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
```

If you want to know more read [Views and Copies in pandas in Practical Data Science](https://www.practicaldatascience.org/html/views_and_copies_in_pandas.html).

Note that built-in python collections also do behave this way, e.g. `dict`s:

```
d1 = dict(x=1,y=2)
d2 = d1
d3 = d1.copy()
d3['x'] = 0
print(d1)  # {'x': 1, 'y': 2}
d2['x'] = 0
print(d1)  # {'x': 0, 'y': 2}
```

Comment: More exactly `df3 = df2` does not involve Pandas views or copies. It is a plain Python assignment and just creates a new reference to the very same object.